# Sharing google appscript or macro with other users

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a `macro` with `appscript` for google sheets and I want to share it with other users so that they can use it in their sheets. 
I have no idea on how to do that. I see that I can share the google script. Is it the best way? Will that ensure that opthers can import this `macro` in their sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best method for me was to publish the script as `webapp`, so that others can use it directly.

On the webapp : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Video on how to make simple webapp : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRQvySxaCW0

Answer (score 1):

You can share the Spreadsheet directly with another user (needs to have edit permissions), that will give them access to the script (macros are stored as scripts). So a user with access to that same Sheet will have access to the macro you made.

If you want to only share the macros (in a way that can be reused in several separate Spreadsheets), you can build it into a library. To do this, you can take a look at [this post](https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm00xCqs7tArGo/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Fdocs%2F0xCqs7tArGo%3Bcontext-place%3Dtopicsearchin%2Fdocs%2Fcategory%243A(spreadsheets)%2420libraries%257Csort%3Adate) which explains how to do just this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the end, I found out about publishing as webapp and that is easier solution for me. It lets others use my script in their sheet.